# Struggling to populate Multi-Dimensional array

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, multidimensional-array

I tried everything I can think of and I am honestly out of ideas. Please provide any hints you possibly can.

Basically I create an array of strings and have a 2-D array that I am trying to fill with the other array in a for loop. What is happening is when the program hits the second loop it just stops. Nothing happens and I can't figure out why!

I've tried the loop in several variations as well as populating it manually but the same thing happens every time.

What i need:

```
array[][] = {[], [], []}
```

What I get: nada

```
public void getEwonData(String data)
{
    JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();

    try
    {
        Object obj = parser.parse(data);
        JsonObject jsonObj = (JsonObject)obj;
        JsonArray arr = jsonObj.get("ewons").getAsJsonArray();
        String[][] array = null;
        for(int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++)
        {

            JsonObject p = (JsonObject) arr.get(i);
            JsonElement varName  = p.get("name");
            JsonElement varStatus = p.get("status");
            JsonElement varDesc = p.get("description");

            String[] varInfo = {varName.toString(), varStatus.toString(), varDesc.toString()};


             //This is where it stops. 
            for(int x = 0; x <= varInfo.length - 1; x++)
            {
                array[i][x] = varInfo[x];
            }
            //I can't get here!
        }

    }
```

I'm honestly out of ideas and would be absurdly appreciative for any assistance.

Comment: Can you post a sample of the data you are passing into the method?

Comment: Your code doesn't compile; `ewonInfo` is an undeclared variable. But a major problem is here: `String[][] array = null;`. You're never assigning an array to `array` so you'll get a `NullPointerException` when you try to access it within the inner for-loop.

Comment: what is `ewonInfo`, where have you declared it?

Comment: Yes to all I fixed the above code, that was just a messup between copy and paste. Corrected and Erwin you are awesome! You were very correct on my array. I think that may be resolving my catch clause wasn't throwing the error but now it is.

Comment: I ACTUALLY declared my String[][] array as pointed out by Erwin. All is resolved now :) thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is resolved. As pointed out by a few people I never initialized my array. After doing so all is working perfectly now.

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume you meant to use varInfo instead of ewonInfo

the code will be:

```
try {
    Object obj = parser.parse(data);
    JsonObject jsonObj = (JsonObject) obj;
    JsonArray arr = jsonObj.get("ewons").getAsJsonArray();
    String[][] array = new String[arr.size()][];
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++) {

    JsonObject p = (JsonObject) arr.get(i);
    JsonElement varName = p.get("name");
    JsonElement varStatus = p.get("status");
    JsonElement varDesc = p.get("description");

    String[] varInfo = {varName.toString(), varStatus.toString(), varDesc.toString()};
    array[i] = varInfo;
    }

}
```

Comment: Yes the variable is named correctly when I was changing thing I forgot to do that, thank you. Also I did assign it directly and the same thing happens everything just stops. I put a println debug statement after teh array to see what was happening and its not getting that far.

Comment: Your problem was just with String[][] array=null; you just needed to initialize it before trying to call array[i][x]